# Gaming for Kids

Tags: video-games

My daughter is getting excited to be playing games with my wife and I. My issue lies in the fact that growing up (some time ago) I wasn't allowed to play games very often. Things change and I get that, so my core question is:

What games should I be introducing her to?

And

How do you introduce a five year old to gaming?

Comment: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/how-should-i-teach-my-son-to-play-video-games/  Lots of interesting replies there...

Answer (score 4):

As a parent, you should pay attention to the [ratings given to each game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_content_rating_system).  The [ESRB](http://www.esrb.org/index-js.jsp) and [PEGI](http://www.pegi.info/en/index/) are probably the best known.  I do not know PEGI well, but I know the ESRB allows you to search by game name and you can see detailed descriptions explaining why that games has that rating.

Comment: That is a valid point, but as a gamer myself, I have found that more often than not the ESRB do little to tell of the amount of skill required to play, the last thing I want is for her to feel video games are too hard to play. Gaming is something I would love to share with her, but all the games I play now are either to violent or to difficult for her.

Comment: @AngelicProgrammer Each child is also going to be unique.  While one kid may excel at racing games and enjoy playing things like Mario Kart, another may prefer adventuring in the world of Pokemon, and a third may prefer the LEGO-like building in Minecraft.  My suggestion would be to try age-appropriate games and find out what your child enjoys playing.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. I would upvote if I could vote.